# Security PermissionFailure Redirect with Core extend hook

Tags: silverstripe

I am using the securefiles extension to keep non members from directly accessing files in their browser.

If the permission check fails, the extension calls the following method:

```php
 function fileNotAuthorized($body = "") {
    Security::permissionFailure($this, $body);
}
```

I looked at Security::PermissionFailure and noticed that towards the end of the class there is an extend hook:

```php
// Audit logging hook
$controller->extend('permissionDenied', $member);
```

By default, the PermissionFailure method redirects users to the admin login page:

```php
$controller->redirect(
            Config::inst()->get('Security', 'login_url')
            . "?BackURL=" . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
        );
```

I would prefer that users be directed to the home or my custom login form page upon being denied permission to access a file.

I have tried hooking into the method via the extend:

```php
class SecurityExtension extends Extension {
function permissionDenied($member) {
    $this->owner->redirect('member-login/login/?BackURL=/thevault/home/');
}
}
```

and then assign this extension in my _config.php file:

```php
Object::add_extension('Security', 'SecurityExtension');
```

Unfortunately, my code is not being accessed and the method continues to redirect the user to the admin login page. The comment above the extend and the param being passed seem to suggest that it is intended for logging members, so I am not sure if using this hook to redirect is possible. If not, is there a more elegant solution to set a custom redirect on Security::PermissionFailure? I would like to avoid hacking the extension.

On a side note, I have also tried setting  set_login_url to my custom login form. While this does redirect non-authorized users to my custom login form correctly, it also redirects /admin to the custom login form - which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this problem today. I just tried

```
Config::inst()->update('Security', 'login_url', '/myCustomLoginFormURL');
```

in mysite/_config.php and it works :)